# Create local or global mongodb collection variable in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So, I have one collection called UserInfo that I use in different functions.  Currently, I just create a local variable in every function that needs to use it.  Is this normal practice?  How expensive it is to create this collection variable?

ex: `var collection = myDb.collection('UsersInfo');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are sharing myDB (mongoClient) across functions, probably passing them as function parameters or using globals.

If you have just one collection, why not do the same as myDb object with collection object.